How to search for many tags?
As the topic says: how to search for posts containing two or more specific tags?

[tag1] [tag2] appears to work.

That works, but it's somehow unhandy. No autocomplete or something?

@SmitJohnth Not that I am aware of. And I'm guessing it isn't something we can just enable on our site. SE would have to implement the functionality. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29277/autocomplete-tags-in-search-box

At least a tip that you can search for tags using search field would be useful.

If you click on one tag (like hash), you see in the right a list of "related tags". Click one one of them, e.g. passwords, and you'll arrive at a page which lists questions having both tags. You can continue this with more tags.
Also, the search field is then pre-filled with these tags in the right syntax ([hash] [passwords] in my example), where you then can add more search terms (in the non-tag form, too, like [hash] [passwords] MD5).
